# Bash autocomplete: List files and directories from other directory

Tags: bash, shell-script, autocomplete, shell-builtin

I wrote a script called `prpsls` which creates or edits files inside the directory `~/proposals`.

Now I'm writing the autocomplete script for it, and I'm trying to set it up in a way that, after I hit **Tab**, the `complete` built-in lists files and directories from the `~/proposals` directory, regardless of the current working directory.

The behavior I'm trying to achieve is exactly like if I did `complete -f prpsls`, but instead of listing files and dirs from the current directory, I want it to always complete to the contents of the `~/proposals` directory.

For example, when I write `ls` and **tab**, it shows:

```bsh
$ pwd
/home/user/base_directory
$ ls
file_01   file_02    subdir_01/
```

If I write `subd` and **Tab**, it autocompletes to `subdir_01`. If I **tab** again, it show the contents of `dir_01`:

```bsh
$ ls subdir_01/
file_03    subdir_02/
```

The behavior I'm looking for is similar:

```bsh
$ pwd
/home/user/any/directory/it/should/not/matter
$ prpsls # Tab here
proposal_01    proposal_02    job_01/
$ prpsls job_01/ # Tab again
proposal_03    proposal_draft
```

My question is: Is it possible to achieve this behavior with the `complete` built-in? If not, how can I achieve this behavior?

I was hoping I could tell to `complete` what directory to use as base directory through a flag, but the only flag I see related to directories is `-d` which is the same as `-A directory`, which generates a list of directories.

Funnily enough, if I use `compgen -f "~/proposals/"`, it **does** list files and directories in `~/proposals`:

```bsh
$ pwd
/home/user/any/directory/it/should/not/matter
$ compgen -f "~/proposals/"
~/proposals/job_01
~/proposals/proposal_01
~/proposals/proposal_02
```

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39729507) question, but:

- The accepted answer does not work for nested directories. (i.e. **Tab** and see the content of a directory)
- The `CDPATH` answer adds more clutter to other commands.
- The `compgen` answer doesn't work for nested directories either.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [this terrific answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40227233/343302) I concocted this completion for command `foo`, which completes files and directories recursively in `~/foodir`:

```
FOO_DIR=$HOME/foodir/

_foo_compgen_filenames() {
    local cur="$1"

    # Files, excluding directories:
    grep -v -F -f <(compgen -d -P ^ -S '$' -- $FOO_DIR"$cur") \
        <(compgen -f -P ^ -S '$' -- $FOO_DIR"$cur") |
        sed -e 's|^\^'$FOO_DIR'||' -e 's/\$$/ /'

    # Directories:
    compgen -d -S / -- $FOO_DIR"$cur" | sed -e 's|'$FOO_DIR'||'
}

_foo_complete() {
    local cur=${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}
    COMPREPLY=( $(_foo_compgen_filenames "$cur") )
}

complete -o nospace -F _foo_complete foo
```

The trick lies in having the `compgen` completion engine complete the full path to the files in `FOO_DIR`, but then removing the `FOO_DIR` path from the completion before it is sent to `complete`. There's also the matter of adding a slash to the end of directory names, which is not a given and `compgen` does not have a native way to return files only (but does have a way to return directories only).

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found some ways and ideas as to how it can be fixed.

A professional could improve upon my way and create a better/perfect solution.

My system is a Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) 4.19.0-16-amd64 with KDE and GNOME

***PART I :***

1. Start a new shell
2. Create the working directory `/home/user/ComBash` and `cd` into it
3. Create a script `mytab` we will bind this script to the complete command

   Now `mytab` looks like:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   echo "MYTAB"
   ```
4. `chmod +x mytab`
5. Create a second script `px` for the complete command

   Now `px` looks like:

   ```
   #/usr/bin/env bash
   echo "PX"
   ```
6. `chmod +x px`
7. Now we start our `px` script with

   ```
   source px
   ```

   or

   ```
   ./px
   ```

   or

   ```
   . ./px
   ```

   The output should be "PX" (it works)
8. Create a new folder named `bin/` in `/home/user/ComBash`

   ```
   mkdir bin
   ```

   our files now are

   ```
   mytab        | script
   px           | script
   bin/         | folder
   ```
9. Now install `mytab` in the `bin/` path of our workdir | `/home/user/ComBash/bin` and delete `mytab` in `/home/user/ComBash/`

   ```
   install mytab bin/mytab && rm mytab
   ```
10. Now add the workdir `bin/` folder to `$PATH`

    ```
    PATH="/home/user/ComBash/bin:${PATH}"
    ```

    or

    ```
    PATH="${PATH}:/home/user/ComBash/bin"
    ```

    check with

    ```
    echo $PATH
    ```
11. Check if `mytab` works:

    - `myt` + <kbd>TAB</kbd> and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
    - `mytab` press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
    - The output is "MYTAB"  (it works)
12. Create some folders, subfolders and empty files inside the folders, we need this folders and files to check if <kbd>TAB</kbd> + <kbd>TAB</kbd> works and check what TAB|TAB shows

Now we have our structure for PART II this solution works only in the current shell

If we close and start a new shell, the `/home/user/ComBash/bin` in `$PATH` is deleted and the bash can't find the `mytab` script in `/home/user/ComBash/bin`, then you have to repeat step 9. (set $PATH) every time you start a new shell.

You can permanently add `/home/user/ComBash/bin` to `$PATH` if you don't want to repeat step 9 every time you start the shell.

***PART II:***

1. Open and edit the `px` file

   I try a lot of this commands too but I will not explain them now, you can try and see the result just uncomment and edit the line you want to try.

   Now px looks like:

   ```
   #/usr/bin/env bash
   #complete -f mytab
   #complete -D -F "/home/user/ComBash" mytab
   #complete -W "$(find /home/user/ComBash/ -path "" -prune -o \( -type d -ls \) -o \( -type f -ls \) | cut -d/ -f 5-)" mytab
   #complete -W "$(find /home/user/ComBash/ -path "" -prune -o \( -type d -ls \) -o \( -type f -ls \) | cut -d/ -f 2- | sed 's/$/\//')" mytab
   #complete -W "$(find /home/user/ComBash/ -path "" -prune -o \( -ls \)))" mytab
   #complete -W "$(ls -R ${MYPATH} | grep /)" mytab
   MYPATH="/home/user/ComBash/"
   complete -W "$(ls -R ${MYPATH})" mytab
   ```

   We bound the complete command to the `mytab` script

   `-W` means we give complete a list of words

   We get the list of words with `ls -R`.

   `ls -R` list all files, subfiles, directories and subdirectories in a given path
2. We start the script px with

   ```
   source px
   ```

   Every time we do changes inside the script we have to restart the script with ( see step 6. in PART I)

   ```
   source px
   ```
3. Now in the shell we use

   `mytab` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>

   and we see the list of all files, subfiles, directories and subdirectories in the given path (`/home/user/ComBash/`)

   We can select every files, subfiles, directories and subdirectoris
   and autocomplete with [TAB]

   Select a subfolder and [TAB] that works

   If we press <kbd>Enter</kbd> the `mytab` script will echo "MYTAB"
4. Lets edit the `mytab` script in `/home/user/ComBash/bin`.

   Now `mytab` looks like:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   MYPATH=/home/user/ComBash
   # echo $MYPATH
   echo $1
   DATA=$(find ${MYPATH} -name ${1})
   echo $DATA
    ####### DO SOMETHING #######
   ```

   `$1` outputs the folder or file we receive from the `px` script
   `DATA` search and outputs the `PATH` of the folder or file

Now we can do something with the current file or folder

`mytab` + <kbd>Tab</kbd> press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: Is this a question or an answer...? It can not be both. If you have an new or related question you must ask it as a new question, not in an answer, that's not how SE works. Also, please take the time to code format your answer, and fix the indentation, to make it more readable.

Comment: This is an answer, that works with with some restrictions. And thx for editing the code to be more readable.